# Converting a vector to full matrix in OpenMx

Tags: r, openmx

I computed the vectorized form of an implied variance-covariance matrix using `mxAlgebra` in OpenMx. Now, I need to reconstruct this to a matrix in order to run the model. OpenMx has the function `vech2full` which does what I want for half-vectorized matrices, but I have a full vectorized matrix.

Thanks for your help!